# Button (install PWA) not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I have a problem with installing my app in Firefox (Add to Home Screen). Everything is working fine on Chrome but on Firefox my button can’t install app (not working). I follow up documentation and I think everything should work. Also I have same problems with install process (add to home screen) on IOS - safari, chrome. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var logData = new Object();
            logData.appVersion = window.navigator.appVersion;
            logData.language = window.navigator.language;
            logData.platform = window.navigator.platform;
            logData.product = window.navigator.product;
            logData.userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
            logData.vendor = window.navigator.vendor;
            console.log(logData);

            if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
                console.log('display-mode is standalone');
                $.post({
                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/installedV})]",
                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
                document.querySelector('.a2hs').remove();
            } 

            else if (window.navigator.standalone === true) {
                console.log('display-mode is standalone');
                $.post({
                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/installedV})]",
                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
                document.querySelector('.a2hs').remove();
            } else {
                $.post({
                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/webAppuse})]",
                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
            }


            var deferredPrompt;
            var addBtn = document.querySelector('.a2hs-button');
            var addDiv = document.querySelector('.a2hs');

            if (addDiv) {
                addDiv.style.display = 'none';

                window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    deferredPrompt = e;

                    addDiv.style.display = 'block';
                    $.post({
                        "url": "[(@{/a2hs/prikazanaopcijazaaddtohomescreen})]",
                        "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    });
                    addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                        deferredPrompt.prompt();

                        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {
                            if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                                console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
                                $.post({
                                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/accept})]",
                                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                                });
                                addDiv.remove();
                            } else {
                                console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
                                $.post({
                                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/denied})]",
                                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                                });
                                addDiv.style.display = 'block';
                            }

                            deferredPrompt = null;
                        });
                    });
                });
            }

            window.addEventListener('appinstalled', function(evt) {
                $.post({
                    "url": "[(@{/a2hs/installed})]",
                    "data": JSON.stringify(logData),
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
                console.log('A2HS installed');
            });
```

Also here is my service worker js code

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    var offlinePage = new Request('offline.html');
    event.waitUntil(
        fetch(offlinePage).then(function(response) {
            return caches.open('std').then(function(cache) {
                console.log('Cached offline page during Install: ' + response.url);
                return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
            });
        }));
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Network request Failed. Serving offline page: ' + error);
                console.log(event.request)
                return caches.open('std').then(function(cache) {
                    return cache.match('offline.html');
                });
            }));

});


self.addEventListener('refreshOffline', function(response) {
    return caches.open('std').then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Offline page updated from refreshOffline event: ' + response.url);
        return cache.put(offlinePage, response);
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me with this? Did a miss something or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beforeinstallprompt is not available in all browsers.
For those where it is not, you might possibly show instructions on how to add a shortcut.

See list here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Comment: any update in this answer ? still firefox doesnot support `beforeinstallprompt `

Comment: That link above should always have the correct answer to your question. Several members of the Firefox team are on Twitter.  You may want to try asking them there if they have any plans on adding support. Search for 'firefox developer'.

Answer (score -2):

If a page's manifest doesn't include the following properties, it will fail the audit:

- A short_name or name property
- An icons property that includes a 192x192 px and a 512x512 px icon
- A start_url property
- A display property set to fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui
- A prefer_related_applications property set to a value other than true.

Caution: A web app manifest is necessary for your app to be installable, but it isn't sufficient. To learn how to meet all the requirements for installability, see the [Discover what it takes to be installable](https://web.dev/discover-installable) post.

[source](https://web.dev/installable-manifest/)

Comment: IIRC, the criteria are standard, and it works fine in Chrome, so it would not appear to be a problem in the web app manifest.